# will N $facet pipelines be equivalent to N concurrent API calls / queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I am facing the decision to either send 100 concurrent API calls / queries to mongoDB or to send 1 query with 100 $facet pipelines.

Will they be more or less equivalent in terms of resources taken up?